# High gain low current amp

Tags: amplifier, bjt, gain, common-emitter

I'm trying to design high gain, low collector current Common Emitter amplifier.
As far as I know, this is well known CE amp for high gain.
[image]
Is there anything I can do for low-current consumption? And I would really appreciate it if you let me know the methods to decide resistor values for high-gain, low-current

Comment: This is a typical "class A" type amplifier.  The #1 drawback to this type of amplifier is its current consumption (the idle current has to be at least as large as the maximum drive current).  The only real way to decrease this is to switch to a different class of amplifier.  [This link may help](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html)

Comment: What do you consider low current? What do you consider high gain?

Comment: The maximum voltage gain of a common emitter amplifier is independent of the current drawn. It's only dependent on the Early effect. It's a different matter when you're trying to drive a load, which you haven't specified.

Comment: egekod - Hi, What are you doing? You have been changing your question after answers were given (please don't do that), then you put things back as they were. Do you need help with using the site? We can try to help, if you explain what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: egekod - You have just removed the part which was the apparent main question originally, where you had asked: "*Is there anything I can do for low-current consumption?*" As I said above, please don't change the question after answers have been received, as it can invalidate those answers. In this case, your [first answer](/a/666347) mainly addressed the low current consumption question, so you cannot now remove it. || As I asked above, please explain what you are trying to achieve by your changes to the question. Thanks.

Comment: egekod - After a question has been answered, it should not be changed in a way that invalidates existing answers. Removing the original question of "*Is there anything I can do for low-current consumption?*" was exactly the type of change to avoid. Therefore as you have not replied to my request for explanation above and it seems you have now gone offline, I have reversed (rolled-back) the changes to the question today. That leaves it in the same state as when it was answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to reduce current consumption in a CE amp is to use self-biasing instead of voltage divider biasing.

Basically you  remove R2, and connect R1 to the collector instead of the positive supply. Now all of the bias current goes into the base instead of some being shunted to ground. It also makes biasing pretty easy, since it adjusts itself to some degree it's rather forgiving of resistor values.

Something like this for instance will give you around 45 dB of gain at around 500 uA current draw. Note that it needs to be followed by a stage with high input impedance, typically at least 10 times the collector resistance (indicated by the 100k load here), the following stage can be something like an emitter follower as it only needs current gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvaMFG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A transistor with high gain has high distortion. This transistor is not clipping. Negative feedback reduces the distortion and reduces the gain:
[image: distortion]